# Remove white background from image

Tags: c#, jquery

Seasons Greetings.

I am using the code that I found on stack overflow to remove the white background.

```
function white2transparent(img)
{
        var c = document.createElement('canvas');
        var w = img.width, h = img.height;

        c.width = w;
        c.height = h;

        var ctx = c.getContext('2d');

        ctx.width = w;
        ctx.height = h;
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, w, h);
        var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0,0, w, h);
        var pixel = imageData.data;

        var r=0, g=1, b=2,a=3;
        for (var p = 0; p<pixel.length; p+=4)
        {
            if (
                pixel[p+r] == 255 &&
                pixel[p+g] == 255 &&
                pixel[p+b] == 255) // if white then change alpha to 0
            {pixel[p+a] = 0;}
        }

        ctx.putImageData(imageData,0,0);

        return c.toDataURL('image/png');
}
```

It's not removing all the white, here is the result I get in my local copy.[image]

Is there a way to remove all the background white using JQuery or C#?

Comment: Because the pixels left are not *white*. For ex,  `(255,255,255) != (255,255,254)` You need some threshold value.....

Comment: All the pixels you want to change are not completely white (255,255,255)

Comment: Oh yes :) will filter out out similar colors.

Comment: Even if you do that, I will still be ugly since no smoothness is applied between colored and alpha pixels

Comment: I am just curious what you would get if you use this formula `(0.2126 R + 0.7152 G + 0.0722 B)` with some threshold value  to determine if color is *close to white* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luma_(video)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking in the suggestions I've modified the code and the white plus similar colors are removed. However it does remove some of the non-white or light gray from inside the image. It's the closest to the best solution so far.

```
function white2transparent(img)
    {
        var c = document.createElement('canvas');
        var w = img.width, h = img.height;

        c.width = w;
        c.height = h;

        var ctx = c.getContext('2d');

        ctx.width = w;
        ctx.height = h;
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, w, h);
        var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0,0, w, h);
        var pixel = imageData.data;

        var r=0, g=1, b=2,a=3;
        for (var p = 0; p<pixel.length; p+=4)
        {
            if ((pixel[p+r] + pixel[p+g] + pixel[p+b] ) > (170*3) - 5)
            {pixel[p+a] = 0;}
        }

        ctx.putImageData(imageData,0,0);

        return c.toDataURL('image/png');
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to include something like a slider so you can add a range for all three channels for each pixel [p+_]. For example, if my value (for my case, in a slider) is 253, then this should apply the value in all three pixels so that pixels[255,255,255] alpha value = 0, pixels[254,254,254] alpha value = 0 and pixels[253,253,253] alpha value = 0. I think you got the idea! :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the remaining pixels are not perfectly white. You need to include some tolerance for the slight variation in color. 
If you want an extremely simple fix, then you could replace your conditional with

```
if (
            pixel[p+r] >= 250 &&
            pixel[p+g] >= 250 &&
            pixel[p+b] >= 250) // if close to white, then change alpha to 0
        {pixel[p+a] = 0;}
```

And that would give you a tolerance of 5 for each color channel. However, it may be better to use a line like:

```
if ((pixel[p+r] + pixel[p+g] + pixel[p+b] ) > (255*3) - 5)
  {pixel[p+a] = 0;}
```

This will give you a tolerance of 5 overall, regardless of the channel that causes discoloration.

An even better solution is to create a GUI element that sets a variable colorTolerance, and use the formula:

```
if ((pixel[p+r] + pixel[p+g] + pixel[p+b] ) > (255*3) - colorTolerance)
  {pixel[p+a] = 0;}
```

This may also remove some of the white pixels in the middle of the image, so keep that in mind.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I've used the second solution and it still left white. However I modified it slightly and will post the result in a short while.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a tolerance for colors that are close to white will work to an extent, but what about images that have white in them that *isn't* part of the background? Even your image has white in it that isn't background. (the polka dots and the belt-like waist thing)

My answer is no; there is no good way to do what you want purely with code. You might be able to use the code that you have to do a rough removal, but each image will need to be reviewed by a person. You need something like photoshop.